# Using Ruby Script to perform a login

Tags: ruby, net-http

my goal is to use a ruby script to perform a login.
The website uses javascript to render the login form therefore I cannot use mechanize. I want to avoid using selenium,

If I were to login with false data, I can see under the network section, that an action url is performed -> 
Request URL: https://www.example.com/admin/bocontroller/bocontroller.cfm?action=dologin

further down I can see the Form Data
-> 
username: Sample
password: 12345678

Based on this I tried to write several scripts (this being the closest i hope...)

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://www.eample.com/admin/bocontroller/bocontroller.cfm?action=dologin")


http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data({'username' => 'Sample', 'password' => '12345678'})

request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

response = http.request(request)
```

Unfortunately My script just stops running... and I am kind of lost. Can anyone give me some hints to lead me into the right direction? IS this the right approach?

Comment: Could be timing out to prevent [CSRF](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures). Out of curiosity, why is it you want to do this?

Comment: If you need JavaScript you may need a full browser solution. Maybe something like [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org)?

Comment: Hello SRack, to make it simple our application has some issue when rebooting. Everytime i need to login 2 times to make it work normal. Otherwise the first 2 people that log in cannot use any functionalities (some caching issue) so before we remove those cookie issues i would like to implement a work around.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems to have gained some traction as a comment, I thought I'd move it to an answer.

There's a good chance this will be timing out to prevent CSRF attacks. Here's a link to the Rails docs explaining this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures.

In a nutshell, sites will send (and require) an authenticity token along with any potentially transformative request (`POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc.), in order to prevent people from sending such requests from outside the domain - as you're doing.

I'm not suggesting you have ill intent, though this prevents someone attempting to gain access to something they shouldn't, should their actions be designed to work in a manner beyond what the site intends.